# WL App installed on server still pointing to local URL for adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I'm having a problem with a simple hybrid app deploying it to a WL 6.1 server.  I am using the **Configure Worklight Build and Deploy Target** window to override the local dev server and put in the server and context for the test server.  After this I do a build (I've tried both the **build all environments** and **run on worklight development server** options)and upload the .wlapp file to the server.  The issue is that when my simple app calls an adapter's procedure that is deployed on the same server, it is always going back to my dev server.  I've verified this by stopping my local and seeing the errors in the log.  Is there a step I'm missing on changing the worklight address?  In 5.x you went and modified the application xml to specify this.

In the log if I shut down my local dev server in eclipse, I get the following in my chrome console when running from my remote server (note xenotp is my dev laptop):

```
POST http://xenotp:10080/bobCATWLProject/apps/services/api/test/common/query net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

FYI, I'm running eclipse with the Worklight Studio Plugin 6.1.0.01-20140310-1427

Answer (score 0):

Where is your app deployed? I have found that I have to manually edit the .plist file in XCode to get the proper server settings configured in iOS.

Also see this related post: [IBM Worklight 6.0 - application uses an incorrect Server URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381754/ibm-worklight-6-0-application-uses-an-incorrect-server-url)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have it figured out now.  There were two main items.  One, I needed to add the WL.Client.connect into my app.  In WL 5 autoconnect was the default.  I don't think that caused the issue, but still good housekeeping.

Two, When you set the **Configure Worklight Build and Deploy Target** options, you can only use **Build All Environments** option to produce a valid wlapp file for deployment to the remote server.  I thought I did this before, but I guess the two combined (not calling connect) caused issues.  In the online information on [The Build All Environments command](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_building_and_deploying_build_all_envs.html) it has the following note:

> Important: If you checked the Build the application to work with a
>   different Worklight server option in the Configure Worklight Build and
>   Deploy Target dialog, then this menu option triggers a build using
>   that Worklight Server information, and recognizes it over the test
>   server setting. If this option is cleared, the build occurs using the
>   build settings for the designated test server.

I did learn if you mess up and upload a wlapp file not built for a remote server, you will get a bunch of 404s for your projects files.

I was able to build an android app and run it from the device and connect to the remote server.  Verified via the DDMS logs.

Comment: The above was done on a windows box.  I've come across a similar issue on OSX, but this does not resolve it.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378925/building-ios-hybrid-app-does-not-update-worklight-plist-or-root-plist-file for other issue.